# How to avoid build failure from ESLint violations with react-scripts/create-react-app?

Tags: create-react-app, react-scripts

I created a fresh project using CRA, and then added a custom eslint config with a single rule, `no-console`, and set it to error log level.

When running `yarn start` to do development, and putting in a console log, the whole build fails and I get a generic error page saying the build failed because there was a console log. But, I put the log there to debug the app, and this isn't a production build.

I also tried seeing if this could be related to custom eslint configs so I violated the rule-of-hooks rule that is default with CRA and saw the same thing happen.

How can I develop with a linting error present?